# Iterating through SVGElement paths with d3js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am following this tutorial:
http://bl.ocks.org/2206529

I want to determine the center area of every state, but I have two problems:

1. How do I iterate over every state's SVG element?
2. How do I determine the middle coordinate of that particular SVG element?

My g element contains many paths, where each path represents a state. It seems that when I use the following code:

```
states.selectAll("path")
```

I want to find the center of the path using:

```
    states.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
        // Get centroid(d)
    });
```

But the function parameter doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the incorrect use of attr. The attr function with a second argument is used for setting an attribute, not simply for iterating over a collection. You should use the each function

> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each
>
> ## selection.each(function)
>
> Invokes the specified function for each element in the current
>   selection, passing in the current datum d and index i, with the this
>   context of the current DOM element. This operator is used internally
>   by nearly every other operator, and can be used to invoke arbitrary
>   code for each selected element. The each operator can be used to
>   process selections recursively, by using d3.select(this) within the
>   callback function.

```
states.selectAll("path").each(function(d, i) {

        // Get centroid(this.d)
});
```